# Check for no extension in switch case in unix

Tags: unix, scripting, hp-ux

I have a script that is using a switch case to check for file extensions and do something on that.

```
# Gets the extension of the file
Extension=${file##*.}
        case ${Extension} in
        abc)
            #Do something
        pqr)
            #Do something
        *)
            #Print the usage
```

The script is called as "script.sh -G filename.abc".

My requirement is to call this script with a file name having no extension.
For ex: script.sh -G FileName.

How do i implement this in my current script?

Answer (score 1):

Always put your variables in quotes unless you *want* it subjected to word splitting and globbing.

```
case "$Extension" in
...
esac
```

When you leave out the quotes, and the extension is empty, your statement expands to:

```
case in
```

which is incorrect syntax.